# Optimized way to bulk delete operation Mongodb Agregation using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, optimization, aggregation-framework

I want to delete data from multiple collection based on ids received using match query from aggregation .

Currently in python i am doing like this but it is taking a lot of time to execute .
`motor` is used

````py
data = studentSource.aggregate([
            {"$match": {'primary_source.utm_source': source_name}},
            {'$project': {'student_id': 1, '_id': 0}}
        ])

        students = [stud async for stud in data]
        if len(students) != 0:
            for i in range(len(students)):
                await studentsPrimaryDetails.delete_many({'_id': students[i]['student_id']})
                await studentSecondaryDetails.delete_many({'student_id': students[i]['student_id']})
                await studentTimeline.delete_many({'student_id': students[i]['student_id']})
                await studentApplicationForms.delete_many({'student_id': students[i]['student_id']})
                await queries.delete_many({'student_id': students[i]['student_id']})
                await leadsFollowUp.delete_many({'student_id': students[i]['student_id']})
                await lead_details.delete_many({'student_id': students[i]['student_id']})

            await studentSource.delete_many({'primary_source.utm_source': source_name})

    ```
Is there any improvement can be done to execute this much faster . Is bulkWrite() useful . But i have to delete data from multiple collection
````

Comment: You may review the data design, usually in MongoDB you have much less collections than you would have in according RDBMS (SQL database). Your code typically looks like for a relational database.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes i agree with you but changing collection at this stage seems hard for us. Initially data design was not that proper

Comment: Also current data design help us to reduce some query time . My idea was to delete bulk id's in one collection to reduce loop iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second Wernfried Domscheit. Delete all matching documents with $in. In Python would be something like this:

```
    data = studentSource.aggregate([
        {"$match": {'primary_source.utm_source': source_name}},
        {'$project': {'student_id': 1, '_id': 0}}
    ])

    students = await data.to_list(length=None)
    ids = [id for id in set([s.get('student_id') for s in students ]) if id ] 
    deletes = [
        studentsPrimaryDetails.delete_many({'_id': {'$in': ids }}),
        studentSecondaryDetails.delete_many({'student_id': {'$in': ids }}),
        studentTimeline.delete_many({'student_id': {'$in': ids }}),
        studentApplicationForms.delete_many({'student_id': {'$in': ids }}),
        queries.delete_many({'student_id': {'$in': ids }}),
        leadsFollowUp.delete_many({'student_id': {'$in': ids }}),
        lead_details.delete_many({'student_id': {'$in': ids }}),
        studentSource.delete_many({'primary_source.utm_source': source_name})
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*deletes)
```

asyncio.gather fires all 8 requests in parallel, but depending on the driver's connection pool settings, some may wait for a free socket.

Comment: Thanks it works faster and asyncio with $in helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ID's into an array and use the array for condition. I have no clue about python, the JavaScript syntax would be this one:

```
student_ids = db.studentSource.aggregate([
    {"$match": {'primary_source.utm_source': source_name}},
    {'$project': {'student_id': 1, '_id': 0}}
]).toArray().map( x => x.student_id)

db.studentsPrimaryDetails.deleteMany({'_id': {$in: student_ids }})
db.studentSecondaryDetails.deleteMany({'_id': {$in: student_ids }})
db.studentTimeline.deleteMany({'_id': {$in: student_ids }})
db.studentApplicationForms.deleteMany({'_id': {$in: student_ids }})
db.queries.deleteMany({'_id': {$in: student_ids }})
db.leadsFollowUp.deleteMany({'_id': {$in: student_ids }})
db.lead_details.deleteMany({'_id': {$in: student_ids }})
```